# manipulate when inview.js is firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i would like to know how i can manipulate the inview.js script that the moment when its fired is not at first pixels in viewport, and the last when the element is going out but rather for example 50pixels later or earlier.
the script of inview.js is

```
(function ($) {
function getViewportHeight() {
    var height = window.innerHeight; // Safari, Opera
    var mode = document.compatMode;

    if ( (mode || !$.support.boxModel) ) { // IE, Gecko
        height = (mode == 'CSS1Compat') ?
        document.documentElement.clientHeight : // Standards
        document.body.clientHeight; // Quirks
    }

    return height;
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var vpH = getViewportHeight(),
        scrolltop = (document.documentElement.scrollTop ?
            document.documentElement.scrollTop :
            document.body.scrollTop),
        elems = [];

    // naughty, but this is how it knows which elements to check for
    $.each($.cache, function () {
        if (this.events && this.events.inview) {
            elems.push(this.handle.elem);
        }
    });

    if (elems.length) {
        $(elems).each(function () {
            var $el = $(this),
                top = $el.offset().top,
                height = $el.height(),
                inview = $el.data('inview') || false;

            if (scrolltop > (top + height) || scrolltop + vpH < top) {
                if (inview) {
                    $el.data('inview', false);
                    $el.trigger('inview', [ false ]);                        
                }
            } else if (scrolltop < (top + height)) {
                if (!inview) {
                    $el.data('inview', true);
                    $el.trigger('inview', [ true ]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

// kick the event to pick up any elements already in view.
// note however, this only works if the plugin is included after the elements are bound to 'inview'
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll();
});
})(jQuery);
```

all credits go to [here](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/)

my attemp was to add a value to offset top `top = $el.offset().top + 50,` which works! but how can i change the value for the bottom up?
thanks ted

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Which you can call like so to achieve your desired effect at 10% from the bottom:

```
    $('.flyIn').waypoint(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    }, { offset: '90%' });
```